# Codigo para pasar audios a texto python

Tags: python, audio

Muchachos necesito de su colaboracion, estoy tratando de ejecutar este codigo, pero me manda a un error que no he podido solucionar.

Basicamente lo que quiero es pasar lo que se habla en el audio a un texto, pues en general a un str, para poder darle un tratamiento y hacer unas predicciones, pero ando atorado en esta parte (pasar el audio a texto)

ACA EL CODIGO.

```
pip install SpeechRecognition
```

```
import speech_recognition as sr
audio="20210101-1.wav"
re = sr.Recognizer() 

with sr.AudioFile(audio) as source:
  
    info_audio = re.record(source)
    texto=re.recognize_google(info_audio,language="es-ES")
    print(texto)
```

Este es el error que me manda, dice: servicio no disponible

hasta donde he podido analizar, creo que no "entiende" el audio, pero he intentado con varios y que considero son muy claros, pero me manda ese mismo error

```
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py in recognize_google(self, audio_data, key, language, show_all)
    839         try:
--> 840             response = urlopen(request, timeout=self.operation_timeout)
    841         except HTTPError as e:

c:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 

c:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 

c:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 

c:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
...
--> 842             raise RequestError("recognition request failed: {}".format(e.reason))
    843         except URLError as e:
    844             raise RequestError("recognition connection failed: {}".format(e.reason))

RequestError: recognition request failed: Service Unavailable
```

Comment: ¿Tus audios pesan más de 10 MB? Ten en cuenta que la [API tiene límites](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/quotas). Considera cortarlos en archivos más pequeños.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez el audio no pesa ni un 1 MB

Comment: ¿Y dura más de un minuto?

Comment: en efecto, dura 32 segundos @JaimeMenéndez